# How to get id of active tab if two modal box are present

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, modal-dialog

HI I have a page where on clicking two different links a modal box appears both of these modal box have different ids.

The problem is I want to get id of first active tab of modal a but by default tab1 of both modal box  is active and it is giving me id of second modal b's tab1 id

I am using these to get active tab id

> var tab_active = $tabs.filter('.active')[0].childNodes[1].id;

I am working on ruby on rails and both of these modals are present on different partial rendered on same page.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get tab id of specific modal I have to set $tabs with value to specific tab id like below

> var $tabs = $('#myModala li');
>       var tab_active =
>   $tabs.filter('.active')[0].childNodes[1].id;

then for modal b

> var $tabs = $('#myModalb li');
>       var tab_active = 
>   $tabs.filter('.active')[0].childNodes[1].id;

and this solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var tab_active = $tabs.filter('.active')[0].attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanx for quick response ........... but it didn't work I had to give $tabs Id of respective modal to solve problem ...

Comment: alert this tab_active and what you got..??

Comment: can you give your html ..??

Comment: Hi I have posted what i used above pls see